# Why is this diceroll function not working?

Tags: python

When I run this program inside a function it doesnt work, but when I run it outside a function it gives me an outcome. I'm new to programming so I'm not sure why.

```
import random
v1 = (random.randint(1,6))
v2 = (random.randint(1,6))
print(v1 + v2)


def roll_dice():
    import random
    v1 = (random.randint(1,6))
    v2 = (random.randint(1,6))
    print(v1 + v2)
    return (roll_dice)
```

Comment: You're not returning the total of the two dice, you're returning the function itself.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please post the full traceback.  That said, a few things.  1) you're not returning the value of ```v1 + v2``` 2)  you're not calling ```roll_dice()``` in the main scope of your script.

Comment: @ewong He never said he's getting an error, there's no traceback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call the function somewhere in your code after declaring it:

- Will print the result `print(roll_dice())`
- Save to a variable `myResult = roll_dice()`
- If it prints itslef then `roll_dice()`

Comment: The function doesn't return the sum of the dice, assigning the result to a variable isn't useful.

Answer (score 0):

The function should return the dice roll, not the function itself. Then you can call the function and print the result.

```
def roll_dice():
    import random
    v1 = (random.randint(1,6))
    v2 = (random.randint(1,6))
    return v1 + v2

roll = roll_dice()
print(roll)
```

Answer (score 0):

The function has to be written first and then called. You probably did the other way around.